# Random population in jQuery masked field

Tags: javascript, jquery, maskedinput

I am using jQuery.maskedInput-1.2.2.js. A DOB field is masked as below:

```
$('.dob').mask("??99/99/9999");
```

We are having an issue. Say, the user entered only last four digits 2000 and tab away. The value now converts to 20/00. The moment he comes and clicks on the input field, random values are popping up e.g 20/00/_000. How to fix this problem?

Thank you very much,

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us your code, as well as what you've tried.

Comment: <code>      <div class="formItem">
      <s:date name="personBean.dob" var="formatvalue"
       format="MM/dd/yyyy" />
      <s:textfield key="form.common.label.dob" name="personBean.dob"
       value="%{#formatvalue}" labelSeparator="" size="20" id="dob"
       cssClass="required dob dateOfBirth" disabled="%{submittedFlag}" />
     </div></code>

Comment: Please put that in your post.